# Design Pattern for implementing this type of lazy loading?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I have a number of classes that implement an interface like this:

```
public interface IProcessor
{
    Foo Foo { get; set; }
    int Process();
}
```

I have a factory that produces these, and I don't know ahead of time how many of them will be produced. The issue is that retreiving the necessary `Foo` objects is expensive, and the property is not actually used in `IProcessor` until `Process` is called.

So if my Factory has a method like this:

```
public IProcessor CreateProcessor(int fooId)
{
    Foo foo = this.Context.GetFoo(fooId);

    return new ImplementedProcessor { Foo = foo };
}
```

I have to call `GetFoo` every time. What I'd really like is something like this:

```
public IProcessor CreateProcessor(int fooId)
{
    this.CurrentlyTrackedFooIds.Add(fooId);

    return new ImplementedProcessor { Foo = what??? };
}
```

The idea being that until `ImplementedProcessor` needed `Foo` to do its `Process` method, it would be queuing up fooId's so that they could be retreived in bulk like so:

```
this.Context.GetAllFoosAtOnceCheaply(this.CurrentlyTrackedFooIds);
```

Are there any lazy loading patterns that could help with something like this? I have full control over this whole project, so I'm not limited by an existing `IProcessor` or `IProcessorFactory` interface. I can think of ways to do this (some sort of delegate maybe?), but none of them seem very clean and I'd like to avoid this kind of thing getting out of hand by having a million different implementations in the project. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are two types that are going to make our lives *super* easy here.  The first is `Lazy`.  When you construct a `Lazy` object you give it a function that returns a value.  Then when you ask for the value of a `Lazy` it starts the function if it wasn't started, waits on the function if it's not complete, and then returns the value.  It never calls the function twice.  If the `Value` is never asked for it also doesn't even fire the function off once.

Then we can create a `ConcurrentDictionary` of `Lazy` objects, so that we make sure to get any existing `Lazy` objects that we have.  Note that its `GetOrAdd` method is observably atomic.  We can be sure that the dictionary won't ever overwrite an existing `Lazy` object with another; it either returns an existing one or sets a new one.  This means that we're never calling `Value` on two different `Lazy` objects that represent the same ID.

After all of that, there's not much to code:

```
private  ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<IProcessor>> lookup =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<IProcessor>>();
public IProcessor CreateProcessor(int fooId)
{
    var lazy = lookup.GetOrAdd(fooId, new Lazy<IProcessor>(Context.GetFoo));

    return new ImplementedProcessor { Foo = lazy.Value };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot about `Lazy`! My real performance problem isn't in retrieving the same fooId multiple times, but that there's a significant gain in retrieving many at the same time. Marking this as the answer since it gives me some good ideas, but I'd appreciate any additional thoughts you may have on this. Thanks again!

Comment: Hm...looking back at this, what would the point of using `Lazy` be in your example? Wouldn't you have to pass in the entire `Lazy` object to `ImplementedProcessor`, and not `lazy.Value`, which would execute it immediately?

Comment: @Ocelot20 Well the goal here is to prevent the need to fetch the same object multiple times; it's effectively a cache.

Comment: Right, but just wondering if `Lazy` does anything special here since `ConcurrentDictionary<int,Foo>` could do pretty much the same work since `lazy.Value` gets called immediately.

Comment: Not quite.  What `Lazy` gives you is that multiple calls *while the value is still being computed* only result in one computation being made.  If you aren't going to be in the situation where something is going to be asked for while something else is computing it, or where doing so simply isn't a major problem, then yes, `Lazy` isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with .NET 4.0, the framework provides a `Lazy<T>` class for this:

```
public interface IProcessor {
    Foo Foo { get; }
    int Process();
}

internal class ImplementedProcessor {
    internal Lazy<Foo> LazyFoo {get;set;}
    public Foo Foo {
        get {
            return LazyFoo.Value;
        }
    }
    public int Process() {
        ...
    }
}

public IProcessor CreateProcessor(int fooId) {
    return new ImplementedProcessor {
        LazyFoo = () => this.Context.GetFoo(fooId)
    };
}
```

This, however, would not retrieve `Foo`s in bulk - the process would go one-by-one. You would save some time only when the `Process()` is never called for some of your `ImplementedProcessor` items.

To do that, you would need to make a cache that is initialized lazily upon retrieval of the first `Foo`, and stays there for the remaining `Foo`s to take cached values. `Lazy<T>` would not fit this as nicely, though. Consider adding a method to `IProcessor` to harvest the required `fooId`s for the cache before calling `Process`, and add a class that retrieves all the IDs of interest.